# Join 6 tables and generate comma seperated values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following six tables:

**distributor_master**

| id | distributor_name | distributor_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DS-1 | distributor1 | NEW |
| DS-2 | distributor2 | NEW |
| DS-3 | distributor3 | UPDATED |
| DS-4 | distributor4 | NEW |

**dealer_master**

| id | dealer_name | dealer_status | d_country_id | d_state_id | d_district_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DL-1 | dealer1 | NEW | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| DL-2 | dealer2 | NEW | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| DL-3 | dealer3 | NEW | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| DL-4 | dealer4 | NEW | 1 | 2 | 3 |

**dealer_distributor_mapping**

| id | dealer_id | distributor_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DL-1 | DS-1 |
| 2 | DL-1 | DS-2 |
| 3 | DL-1 | DS-4 |
| 4 | DL-2 | DS-2 |
| 5 | DL-2 | DS-4 |
| 5 | DL-3 | DS-4 |
| 5 | DL-4 | DS-1 |

**country_master**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | India |
| 2 | USA |

**state_master**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Maharashtra |
| 2 | Delhi |
| 3 | Gujrat |

**district_master**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mumbai |
| 2 | Nashik |
| 3 | Pune |

I want to display the field "*distributor_master.distributor_name*" as a comma-seperated value, with a bunch of other information from the other tables as follows:

| id | dealer_name | distributor_name | country_name | state_name | district_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DL-1 | dealer1 | distributor1,distributor2,distributor4 | India | Maharashtra | Mumbai |
| DL-2 | dealer2 | distributor2,distributor4 | USA | Maharashtra | Nashik |
| DL-3 | dealer3 | distributor4 | USA | Maharashtra | Nashik |
| DL-4 | dealer4 | distributor1 | India | Delhi | Pune |

I have tried below query but not able to get output as needed.

```
SELECT dlm.id              AS id,
       dlm.dealer_name     AS dealer_name,
       dm.distributor_name AS distributor_name,
       cm.name             AS country_name,
       sm.name             AS state_name,
       dsm.name            AS district_name  
FROM dealer_master AS dlm
JOIN dealer_distributor_mapping AS ddm ON dlm.id = ddm.delaer_id 
JOIN distributor_master AS dm          ON ddm.distributor_id = dm.id
JOIN country_master as cm              ON dlm.d_country_id = cm.id
JOIN state_master as sm                ON dlm.d_state_id = sm.id
JOIN district_master as dsm            ON dlm.d_district_id = dsm.id
WHERE dlm.dealer_status = 'NEW';
```

If anyone have idea how to do this please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried to solve it? encountered any problems while trying?

Comment: @odaiwa yes i tried using join but data not get in proper comma seperator format. Its give in seperate row

Comment: edit the question and add your tries

Comment: @odaiwa added the my query in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing @lemon 's answer, in case you are in versions previous to MySQL 8.0 (And can't use CTEs), you would have to add every column to the `GROUP BY` clause that is not affected by an aggregate function.

```sql
SELECT
  dlm.id as id,
  dlm.dealer_name,
  group_concat(dm.distributor_name),
  cm.name as country_name,
  sm.name as state_name,
  dsm.name as district_name
FROM dealer_master dlm
JOIN dealer_distributor_mapping AS ddm ON dlm.id = ddm.delaer_id 
JOIN distributor_master AS dm          ON ddm.distributor_id = dm.id
JOIN country_master as cm              ON dlm.d_country_id = cm.id
JOIN state_master as sm                ON dlm.d_state_id = sm.id
JOIN district_master as dsm            ON dlm.d_district_id = dsm.id
WHERE dlm.dealer_status = 'NEW'
group by dlm.id, dlm.dealer_name, cm.name, sm.name, dsm.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function on the distributor names, to generate your comma-separated field. Then join back to the other tables with respect to the corresponding matching ids.

```
WITH csv_mapping AS (
    SELECT ddm.dealer_id,
           GROUP_CONCAT(dm.distributor_name) AS distributor_name
    FROM       dealer_distributor_mapping ddm
    INNER JOIN distributor_master dm ON ddm.distributor_id = dm.id
    GROUP BY ddm.dealer_id
)
SELECT dlm.id,
       dlm.dealer_name,
       m.distributor_name,
       cm.name AS country_name,
       sm.name AS state_name,
       dm.name AS district_name
FROM       dealer_master   dlm
INNER JOIN csv_mapping       m ON dlm.id            = m.dealer_id
INNER JOIN country_master   cm ON dlm.d_country_id  = cm.id
INNER JOIN state_master     sm ON dlm.d_state_id    = sm.id
INNER JOIN district_master  dm ON dlm.d_district_id = dm.id
WHERE dlm.dealer_status = 'NEW'
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yVL2Vs8SdSTz5fmEYAt55/1).

Comment: but in my mysql workbench and phpmyadmin its not working

Comment: Check the tables declaration in the provided demo. Are there any differences with yours?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this one ,

```
SELECT dealer_name, distributor_name, country_master.name as country_name, state_master.name as state_name, district_master.name as district_name FROM dealer_master
LEFT JOIN dealer_distributor_mapping ON dealer_distributor_mapping.dealer_id = dealer_master.id
LEFT JOIN distributor_master ON distributor_master.id = dealer_distributor_mapping.distributor_id
LEFT JOIN country_master ON country_master.id = dealer_master.d_country_id
LEFT JOIN state_master ON state_master.id = dealer_master.d_state_id
LEFT JOIN district_master ON district_master.id = dealer_master.d_district_id
WHERE dealer_master.dealer_status = 'NEW';
```

You can use INNER JOIN if you absolutely need to match all data.

Comment: using this get data distributor name in sperate row. I want each dealer with distributor name comma seperator